# What am I missing in order to connect BaasBox data to MapBox presentation layer?

Tags: jquery, ios, mapbox, geojson, baasbox

Good Evening, 
I am working on an iOS mobile application that allows the mobile user to send geolocation data to the backend (BaasBox). I then want to be able to display all of the collected geolocation data, from the BaasBox database, in an online Mapping tool (MapBox).

What strategies are available to retrieve/load the BaasBox geolocation data, and display it in MapBox?

What technologies am I missing that makes this "connection" between the BaasBox data, and the MapBox presentation layer?

I am in the design phase of this project, and I want to be sure I am using the right tools for the job. Any guidance in this implementation would be greatly appreciated.

Very Respectfully,
Robbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just in case this is looked at by anyone else, After more research, I decided to change the stack.

mobile client (ios and android) --> Firebase/geoFire --> Leaflet (in Browser)

This stack will accomplish what my app needs, and allows for me to scale up within Firebase if it does become successful.